# How Can I change the icon made with prop over transform option in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have a React accordion component with defined themes and icons.
I need to change the icon with on click via transform option in styled components and storybook.

Also upon clicking, the background color of the title div and content div needs to change.

I have defined color prop and icon, but not sure what is next?

Here is my React component:

```
import { string, node, oneOf, bool } from "prop-types"
import * as Styled from "./Accordion.styled"
import Icon from "design-system/components/icon"
import React, { useState } from 'react'


const Accordion = ({ children, icon, text, button,
  color, activeColor, }) =>  {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);
  return (
  <Styled.Accordion
  color={color}
  >
    <Styled.Title onClick={() => setIsActive(!isActive)}
    color={isActive ? activeColor : color}
    > {text}
    <Styled.Icon color={color}>
    <Icon name={icon}/>
    </Styled.Icon> 
    </Styled.Title>
    {isActive &&
    <Styled.Content
    color={isActive ? activeColor : color} >
    {children} 
    {button}
    </Styled.Content>
    }
  </Styled.Accordion>
);
}

Accordion.propTypes = {
  text: string.isRequired,
  children: node.isRequired,
  icon: string,
  name: string,
  button: node,
  color: oneOf(["primary", "neutrals", "grey"]),
  activeColor: oneOf(["primary", "neutrals", "grey"]),
}

Accordion.defaultProps = {
  children: null,
  icon: null,
  name: null,
  button: null,
  color: "",
  activeColor: "",
}

export default Accordion
```

and here are the styles:

```
import styled from "@emotion/styled"
import { css } from "@emotion/react"

export const Accordion = styled.div`
 display: flex;
 text-decoration: none;
 width: auto;
 height: auto;
 flex-direction: column;
 align-items: flex-start;
 justify-content: start;
 border-radius: 30px;
 `
export const Title = styled.div`
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-flex;
  gap: 161px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
  padding: 10px 0px 0px 10px;
  color: ${({ color, theme }) => {
  switch (color) {
    case "grey":
      return theme.colors.grey[600]
    case "neutrals":
      return theme.colors.neutrals[100]
    case "primary":
      return theme.colors.primary[500]
    default:
      return theme.colors.grey[600]
  };
}};
background-color: ${({ color, theme }) => {
  switch (color) {
    case "grey":
      return theme.colors.grey[600]
    case "neutrals":
      return theme.colors.neutrals[100]
    case "primary":
      return theme.colors.primary[500]
    default:
      return theme.colors.grey[600]
  }
}};
`

export const Content = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: start;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 10px 10px;
  padding: 10px 100px 0px 10px;
  background-color: ${({ color, theme }) => {
    switch (color) {
      case "grey":
        return theme.colors.grey[600]
      case "neutrals":
        return theme.colors.neutrals[100]
      case "primary":
        return theme.colors.primary[500]
      default:
        return theme.colors.grey[600]
    }
  }};
  color: ${({ color, theme }) => {
    switch (color) {
      case "grey":
        return theme.colors.grey[600]
      case "neutrals":
        return theme.colors.neutrals[100]
      case "primary":
        return theme.colors.primary[500]
      default:
        return theme.colors.grey[600]
    }
  }};
`

  export const Icon = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  `
```

Comment: "_via translate option_": what do you mean? There is no "translate" in the code you show? Do you mean an extra Accordion prop?

Comment: Sorry I meant transform not translate :) I think this might be possible usein a prop and and this option?

Answer (score 1):

I see you're already passing `icon` as a prop to this component. If you want to change the icon on click, you can create a state and set that as the initial value, then update it when you like.

```js
const [icon, setIcon] = useState(props.icon);
```

(you can avoid using a prop as the initial value by [lifting state up](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#lifting-state-up) and passing an additional click handler down from the parent function)

and then you might want to create an `onClick` method for the icon div that sets this icon:

```js
const changeIcon = () => {
    // some logic to select an updated icon
    setIcon(newIcon);
}
```

or you could just pass an icon to this method:

```js
const changeIcon = newIcon => {
    setIcon(newIcon);
}
```

and assign it to said div:

```
return (
    ...
    <Styled.Icon onClick={changeIcon}>
        <Icon name={icon} />
    </Styled.Icon>
    ....
);
```

For doing anything when the "background" is clicked, you can assign a similar click listener to the Accordion component (or whichever component's background you want to have this behaviour on) and if you don't want anything to happen if an element on top of this background is clicked, you can stop this event propagation with `event.stopPropagation()`, where `event` is automatically passed to the click handler:

```
return (
    <SomeElement onClick={event => event.stopPropagation()} />
);
```

I hope that answers your questions. Consider going over [the short React tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html) that covers the basics of React, including when to use state.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, however I not wish to change the icon via the prop, but with the help of on click function. Use state should be used only to uncover the accordion's body on the onclick method when user click on the title. Also, when uncovered- accordions background color, and font colors should change based on the color prop and styled components. Icon should get change not via useState, but on translate option in styled components. Can you please advise on that?

Answer (score 0):

> change the icon with on click

Assuming you get an "active icon" from props, then just switch it depending on your `isActive` state:

```
const Accordion = ({
  icon,
  activeIcon,
}) => {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Styled.Title onClick={() => setIsActive(!isActive)}>
      <Styled.Icon>
        {/* Provide the desired name prop value depending on state */}
        <Icon name={isActive ? activeIcon : icon}/>
      </Styled.Icon>
    </Styled.Title>
  );
};
```

---

> the background color of the title di[v] and content div needs to change

...possibly:

> via transform option in styled components

For this, you can indeed use styled-components [adapting based on props](https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#adapting-based-on-props):

```
const Accordion = ({
  color,
  activeColor,
}) => {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Styled.Title
      onClick={() => setIsActive(!isActive)}
      color={isActive ? activeColor : color}
    >
    </Styled.Title>
  );
};

// Accordion.styled
export const Title = styled.div`
  // Adapt the bgColor value based on color prop
  background-color: ${(props) => props.color};
`;
```

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your help. For the icon, I was asked to do this via translate option, not state. Could you please advise how can I do this? I manage to add isActive color and it gets change, however in a wrong way :) I.E when I set prop value in storybook as grey everything gets grey, before and after clik :) Can you please check and advise where there is a mistake?

Comment: "_do this via translate option, not state_": sorry I do not understand what you mean by that?

Comment: "_when I set prop value in storybook as grey everything gets grey, before and after clik_": without a [mcve] it is hard to tell what could be wrong.